# Suppressing comma inside double quotes while reading CSV file into .Xdf file Using rxImport function

Tags: r, csv, bigdata, revolution-r

I am trying to convert a large `.CSV` file into an `.Xdf` file by using the `rxImport()` function with the below code:

```
rxImport(inData = "/poc/revor/data/ext_roll36_chrg_vol.csv",
         outFile = "/poc/revor/data/ext_roll36_chrg_vol.xdf", 
         overwrite = TRUE, rowsPerRead = 100000,
         colClasses = c(SE_NO = "character", 
                        HIER_ROLLUP_CD = "character", 
                        CUR_MO_CT ="numeric", 
                        CUR_MO_AM = "numeric", 
                        AD_LINE_1_TX = "character",
                        AD_LINE_2_TX = "character",
                        SUBMIT_DT = "character", 
                        UPDT_TS = "character"),
         transforms = list(SUBMIT_DT = as.Date(SUBMIT_DT, format="%d%b%Y")))
```

But this file contains many records like:

```
0200001097,SS,625,236899.000,"KRAV MAGA WORLDWIDE, INC.","KRAV MAGA WORLDWIDE, INC.",01MAY2014,07JUN2014:01:08:57.000000
```

As you can see the columns `AD_LINE_1_TX` & `AD_LINE_2_TX` contain commas inside the double quotes.

I have tried using the `type = "text"` argument, but then it reads the first column i.e `SE_NO` as `numeric` even though its type is showing as `character`.  This is the issue with all the `numeric` fields which I want to read as a `character`.

And If I transform the column using the `transform` argument into `character` as:

```
transforms = list(SE_NO = as.character(as.numeric(SE_NO)))
```

Then the value of `SE_NO` column changes from `0200001097` to `0200001000` in the transformation from character(exponential representation) `2.000011e+08` to numeric.

So Is there any other way to suppress the comma inside the double quotes with out affecting other columns?

Please let me know in case any further information is needed on the same.

Comment: Does this `CSV` have a header row?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need...

```
input_file <- "/poc/revor/data/ext_roll36_chrg_vol.csv"
output_file <- "/poc/revor/data/ext_roll36_chrg_vol.xdf"

my_colInfo <- list(list(index = 1, type = "character", newName = "SE_NO"),
                   list(index = 2, type = "character", newName = "HIER_ROLLUP_CD"),
                   list(index = 3, type = "numeric", newName = "CUR_MO_CT"),
                   list(index = 4, type = "numeric", newName = "CUR_MO_AM"),
                   list(index = 5, type = "character", newName = "AD_LINE_1_TX"),
                   list(index = 6, type = "character", newName = "AD_LINE_2_TX"),
                   list(index = 7, type = "character", newName = "SUBMIT_DT"),
                   list(index = 8, type = "character", newName = "UPDT_TS"))

input_source <- RxTextData(file = input_file, 
                           colInfo = my_colInfo,
                           delimiter = ",",
                           quotedDelimiters = TRUE,
                           useFastRead = TRUE)

rxImport(inData = input_source,
         outFile = output_file, 
         overwrite = TRUE, rowsPerRead = 100000,
         transforms = list(SUBMIT_DT = as.Date(SUBMIT_DT, format="%d%b%Y")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, It does suppress the quotes however it is showing a error again as : 



Error in rxCall("Rx_ImportDataSource", params) :

may be due to value of column  "AD_LINE_1_TX" having value as """KIMBEL PLUMBING, INC."""  i.e having three quotes before & after the value. So is there any way to remove the extra quotes present entirely in this column?